# WSO2 EMM - Location

Tags: android, gps, wso2, wso2-iot

How can I force the devices to turn on gps (location) when connected to enterprise network, and how can I access to latitude and longitude of it in wso2_emm?

Answer (score 1):

Since WSO2 EMM agent is running as the device administrator on the device, it has relevant permissions to retrieve location (GPS) information of the device at any time. Furthermore, the Android agent retrieves the latest updated location information over three different methods such as WiFi, Network and GPS. So you will be able to see the latest updated location from the map in device details page. Other than that EMM does not provide co-ordinates (latitude and longitude) directly.

Comment: So it should always show device location on device's tab on device management, but it didn't show the location.
what is store for location in emm, As it show google map it should store co-ordinates or place's name.
I want to find the place of the device, if someone forget wher he put it.

Comment: Obviously it should appear in the device detail page. However if you want to view it from the database, check the **"received_data"** column of the **"notifications"** table under **"INFO"** record in the **WSO2EMM_DB**.

Comment: [Here](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=15wypdt&s=8) is the database's query result, As I don't know the correct feature_description and feature_code for location I test which i suggest from D:\EMM\Carbone_Home\dbscripts\emm\mysql. but no record with this info is available.
Also it didn't show location on device detail [page](http://tinypic.com/r/20o6y8/8).

Thanks

Comment: Location didn't work when device location is turn off, How can I trun it on using wso2 agent, so that I could access to it always?
In the agent logcat I see that for location it send latitude and longitude for location object. how can I access to this in emm server? (but this is logcat error taged by processMessage!)